# Dynamicaly Reference Mongodb userschema on post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have an express app where users can create accounts and create posts. I have 2 user sigin in methods; Local and Twitter. The problem is that in my posts schema I can only reference 1 schema I want to automatically accosiate either the LocalSchema or TwitterSchema based on what the user is signed in with.

To do this I have tried using mongodb dyanamic ref. This is what I have so far:

*models/post.js*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const PostsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  postBody: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'userModel',
  },
   userModel: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
     enum: ['LocalUser', 'TwitterUser'],
   },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostsSchema);

let model;
 try {
   model = mongoose.model('Posts', PostsSchema);
   model = mongoose.model('LocalUser', new Schema({ username: String }));
   model = mongoose.model('TwitterUser', new Schema({ username: String }));
 } catch (error) {
   model = mongoose.model('Posts', PostsSchema);
 }
 module.exports = model;
```

*routes/posts.js*

```
 const Posts = require('../models/Posts');
 const LocalUser = require('../models/LocalUser');
 const TwitterUser = require('../models/TwitterUser');

router.post(
  '/submit',
  ensureAuth,
  async (req, res) => {
    const { user: { username } = {} } = req;
    const { postTitle, postBody } = req.body;
      try {
         const luser = await LocalUser.create({ username });
         await model.create({
           postTitle,
           postBody,
           userModel: 'LocalUser',
           user: luser,
         });

         const tweeter = await TwitterUser.create({ username });
         await model.create({
           postTitle,
           postBody,
           userModel: 'TwitterUser',
           user: tweeter,
         });
        res.redirect('/profile');
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/500');
      }
  }
);
```

When I try make a post I get:

```
Error: Posts validation failed: postBody: Path `postBody` is required., postTitle: Path `postTitle` 
is required.
```

Is the problem how I'm requiring my models or something else? I've been stuck on this for a while and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with your models. It seems to me like the post data is not coming across. Log { postTitle, postBody }  and see what you see.

Comment: When I console log postBody and Post title I get the postBody and postTitle. Under that it says Posts validation failed: `Posts validation failed: userModel: Path `userModel` is required., postBody: Path `postBody` is required., postTitle: Path `postTitle` is required.`